# Unit Testing methods with Trace.Write() in ASP.NET with MSTest

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to add some unit tests to some legacy code.  Many of the functions begin with `Trace.Write`

```vb
Function FormatDate(ByVal inputAsString As String) As String
    Trace.Write("Function FormatDate")
```

When I run Tests against the full set of ASP.NET Unit test attributes, it takes too long:

```vb
<TestMethod(), _ 
HostType("ASP.NET"), _ 
UrlToTest("http://localhost:25153/WebSite1"), _
AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\WebSite1", "/WebSite1")>
Public Sub FormatDateTest()
```

In response, I've just been testing an instance of the class itself:

```vb
<TestMethod(), _ 
Public Sub FormatDateTest()
```

This works quickly, but I get an "Object Reference No Set to an instance of an Object" error when I arrive at `Trace.Write()`

Is there some way I can test if I'm running unit tests and not call trace?  Can I mock an html object so that it doesn't throw an excpetion?  Can I push right past the exception? Should I just get rid of Trace?  I'd kind of like to keep the tests within MsTest since I'm in a pretty strictly Microsoft derivitive product shop.

**Update**

Here's the stacktrace from the `NullReferenceException`

```
at System.Web.UI.UserControl.get_Trace()
at Applications.Interface.UCparent.FormatDate(String inputAsString, Boolean isFuzzy, Char& precision) 
in \\...\UCparent.ascx.vb:line 285
```

The `Trace.Write` method returns the `System.Web.TraceContext` of the Page on which it is called. Essentially, it is idential to writing `Page.Trace.Write`

The problem is, when using @[Ross Presser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864696/ross-presser)'s suggestion of adding `HttpContext.Current` to the Unit Test Setup, it's still the case that `Page.Trace Is Nothing = True`

```vb
'This Works
HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("HttpContext.Current")
'This Doesn't
Page.Trace.Write("Page.TraceContext")
'This Doesn't
Trace.Write("Page.TraceContext")
```

I can go in and change all the Trace.Write methods to use the HttpContext intstead of the default page context, but that runs into the same problem as earlier.  Also the `Trace` property on `Page` has no setter, so it seems difficult to just give the page some context without it naturally inheriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to distinguish between the test environment and the live environment:

```
If HttpContext.Current Is Nothing Then
```

It may be that the REASON your Trace.Write statements are throwing the NullReferenceException is because Trace is relying on there being an HttpContext. If so, you could mock the HttpContext:

```
<TestInitialize()>
Public Sub Setup()
    'Since this is not a real web app, we need to mock at least
    'the current HttpContext
    HttpContext.Current = New HttpContext( _
        New HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""), _
        New HttpResponse(New StringWriter()) _
    )
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Checking for `HttpContext.Current` works, but of course I'd have to change each line of code that calls `Trace.Write`.  I'd prefer your second option, but I'm still get a `NullReferenceException` even after providing the HttpContext in my TestSetup method.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace for the `NullReferenceException`?